# Spring boot does not refer id of user in database

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

After truncating my database and re-insert it with script my spring doesn't refer to the latest data anymore. But somehow when I create new user, the hibernate still create user id as 1, which in fact already existed after I committed my script. Refreshing or restarting project won't help. Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: give us more details please

Comment: Hi basically I truncated all the data from my database in postgres databse. And reload it with the set of insert. But when I add new data through jpa, it keeps said that the id = 1 already exist which means that somehow JPA may think that the database is empty and it start the id from 1 instead of the following to the latest data which should be 21 instead of 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases like oracle maintain the sequence buffer for the primary key, you will have to set your sequence number in the sequence table then it will start generating the primary key to the next number in the sequence.

In Postgres also you can do the same and this will solve your problem.

Comment: Postgres can be set to do the same, and would have the same requirement. See documentation for [Create Sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html).